# Proof of one of the most beautiful equations in Math.

Tags: proof-explanation

$\cfrac{1}{1^2} + \cfrac{1}{2^2} + \cfrac{1}{3^2} + ...... \infty = \cfrac{{\pi}^2}{6}$

Often termed as *one of the most beautiful equations in math*:

I tried devising a proof for the above formula.

But I got stuck just as soon as I begun. Addition of any two or more rational numbers **always** results in a rational number. The $LHS$ is rational but the $RHS$ is irrational. How is this possible?

Comment: A convergent sequence of rational numbers can have an irrational limit.  That's how this equality is possible.

Comment: Adding finitely many rational numbers yields a rational, but with infinitely many anything is possible.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro

Comment: Evaluating the sum on the left is called the Basel problem. Euler's beautiful, non-rigorous solution was one of the highlights of the history of math. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: The Youtube channel 3Blue1Brown (which any Math enthusiast probably knows) has a beautiful intuitive explanation on this result. Perhaps complimenting the technical proofs suggested by others with such an intuition is a good idea : )

Comment: Why do people put $\infty$ there as a summand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least as far as your question is concerned, take your favorite irrational number. For instance we can take
$$\pi(=3.1415...)$$
and write it as an infinite convergent sum
$$
\pi=3+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{4}{100}+\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{5}{10000}+\cdots
$$
So actually, every irrational can be viewed as the sum of an infinite series consisting of rational numbers.

Comment: ... an infinite series whose general terms are all rational numbers.

Comment: Yeah thanks -- tired.

Comment: And here I was ready to bust out my favorite elementary proof of the Basel problem. Good answer though.